# iframe php injection into my html site

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have quite a small website, with a total of 3 webpages, consisting of only html, css and jquery...now on one of my .html pages, I have this annoying iframe injection (the source file is php) that is added on top of my body tag each time i load my page. Now I deleted all my referenced stylesheets, plugins etc one by one but the only way  get rid of it is if I delete all my content for that page. How do I get rid of this iframe? Any tips?

Note that the same plugins I used on my other pages I used on this 'hacked page', except for one plugin...but removing that one plugin does not fix it...?

Here is the iframe code I got by inspecting the element: this whole part below is injected

```
<div style="padding-left: 120px;">
<iframe width="728" scrolling="no" height="90" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" src="http://b.admedia.com/banner.php?id=18793&sr=1&injection_code=true&subid=FC&ip=[IP]&ua=[UA]&transparency=[TR]&highlight=0&style=1&appnxsId=860932&size=728x90&search=digital cameras&force=1&ref=&bpage=">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, it is hosted by my ISP, linux server, mySQL, php

Comment: Is that iframe appear in your source? Or is it being added by javascript? Is your page a pHP page? When was it last modified, and did you modify it?

Comment: No, does no not appear in my source. I regularly update my page(every few hours cause I'm working/updating on that page)...this problem started earlier today. No my page is .html

Comment: It's only on this file? You can delete it and have a file of different names and it is OK? What's this file name?

Comment: Maybe you have some malware that's injecting it - run SpyBot S&D or something to get rid of any malware.

Comment: @DextrousDave so it's being added by JavaScript? Start removing scripts to see what's adding it. Or does your page initially not have it, then it appears after some time (in the source)?

Comment: Yes, only that file. other files are fine...I copied and pasted the code for that file into a new file with new file name, and same problem occurs...but I don't see anything strange in my code. the filename is gallery.html

Comment: Ok, same code but different file name and issue persists means its something in your code. Sounds like you didn't clear everything out of the file as you suggest in your question. Paste your code here and let's see.

Comment: Found the problem...See the answer below, Hamish is right. I got the issue in FF and Chrome but not in IE. I checked that I have recently installed the same plugin in both FF and Chrome called freecorder6, but not in IE...

Comment: @ sachleen: I still did not see any strange code in my file...how did they do it then?

Comment: @Matt - Thanks, it was malware indeed. Found it luckily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly have malware on your PC.

For example, see [this](http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=48e60a603f2b11cb5180fdbe545e8173) and [this](http://contagiodump.blogspot.co.nz/2012/02/purple-haze-bootkit.html). Most likely you have a trojan that is injecting the code into explorer, enabling the attacker to farm for ad clicks.

You can confirm by trying a different browser or running a virus/malware scanner.

Comment: Yup, you are so right...got the problem in FF and Chrome, but not IE. FF and Chrome have both a plugin called Freecorder 6(great plugin btw but if it is doing this crap, it should go...)

Comment: thank you very much...One thing I noticed is that the malicious code also introduced a google related script, which looked like a google analytics tracking script...which explains your farming theory...